# XHR call returns HTML, how to use that and reload the entire page?

Tags: ajax, jquery

A XHR call returns HTML, how do I tell the browser to use that and reload the entire page? I know the main use for XHR is to do partial page fresh but my case is a bit special. Thanks.

Or put it in a more general term, what is the best way to use JS to simulate a browser form GET request? window.location.replace("url")?

Comment: do you mean you want to refresh the entire page with javascript after making an ajax call...? why not just serve the page normally?

Comment: @contagous : I know how my question sounds. but it is a special case.

Answer (score 0):

rather than trying to reload or something, have you considered doing something like

```
document.body.innerHTML = [the string HTML that you got back from XHR];
```

Or perhaps you could do it by building a new DOM from the HTML and then swapping it in?